# How to print each day of the week as Column 1 in a MySQL query where not all days have a result

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

I have the following query which shows the number of hours billed for each day of the week

```
SELECT DAYNAME(record_date),
      sum(value)
FROM acx_time_records
WHERE
  acx_time_records.state = 3
  AND record_date >= '2012-10-1' AND record_date <= '2012-10-7'    
  AND user_id = 7 
  GROUP BY
  dayname(acx_time_records.record_date)
  ORDER BY weekday(acx_time_records.record_date)
```

The above query outputs the following result:

```
Tuesday    9.75
Friday     1
```

The issue I have is that I need to plot the values to a graph which has the X-Axis already defined as each day of the week:

```
 Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
```

Therefore, I'm needing to pass each of the days of the week for the result, instead of just the particular days/hours that show up in the result. I thought about making a join to a new table which has each calendar day of the week and a day index, but I'm not sure how that would be possible. The ideal output would be:

```
Monday    0
Tuesday   9.75
Wednesday 0
Thursday  0
Friday    1
Saturday  0
Sunday    0
```

Any tips/suggestions for how I might accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. I know this may also be facilitated by combining MySQL with PHP, but I'm trying to do this in a way that would only require MySQL if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution with LEFT JOIN.

You can use an additional table or use some SELECTs with UNIONs as newfurniturey suggested. Also I have located WHERE filter inside the joined table.

```
CREATE TABLE week_days(
  week_day_num INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO week_days(week_day_num) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7);

SELECT
  DAYNAME(atrrecord_date),
  SUM(atr.value),
  COALESCE(SUM(atr.value) , 0)
FROM week_days wd
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT * FROM acx_time_records
      WHERE
        acx_time_records.state = 3
        AND record_date >= '2012-10-1' AND record_date <= '2012-10-7'    
        AND user_id = 7 
    ) atr
    ON wd.week_day_num = DAYOFWEEK(atr.record_date)
GROUP BY
  DAYOFWEEK(atr.record_date);
```

Comment: that works! the WHERE filter inside the joined table did the trick. thank you. Do you have any suggestion for how I can show 0 as the value, if the result for a particular day (atr.value) is Null?

Comment: Try to use COALESCE function, e.g. COALESCE(SUM(atr.value)
, 0).

Comment: where would I put that function?

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest going with your original idea of joining on another table, but you can make it a simple alias-table with a `LEFT JOIN` clause:

```
SELECT
    days.day,
    IF (value IS NULL, 0, SUM(value))
FROM
    (SELECT 'Monday' AS day UNION SELECT 'Tuesday' UNION SELECT 'Wednesday' UNION SELECT 'Thursday' UNION SELECT 'Friday' UNION SELECT 'Saturday' UNION SELECT 'Sunday') AS days
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT * FROM acx_time_records
        WHERE 
            acx_time_records.state = 3
            AND record_date >= '2012-10-1' AND record_date <= '2012-10-7'    
            AND user_id = 7 
    ) AS acx_time_records
        ON DAYNAME(record_date) = days.day
GROUP BY
    days.day
ORDER BY weekday(acx_time_records.record_date)
```

This will cause every day of the week to be selected (as an individual row) and the `SUM()` for each, `0` if no days are defined, will be grouped accordingly.

Comment: This is still returning only Tuesday and Friday in the results. Not sure why that is. Any idea?

Comment: also in your example, is value coming from the day table? Or from the acx_time_records table? In my code it's coming from acx_time_records.values

Comment: @DanielC Sorry, signed off early last night. It looks like it didn't work because your `WHERE` clause limits the actual days returned; If you put the `acx_time_records` into a sub-select with the `WHERE` clause and join on that it will work (I've updated my answer to show). Also, the `value` is coming from the `acx_time_records` table - the only thing from the days table is the name of the day.

Comment: Thanks @newfurniturey - that seemed to be the issue. The answer I selected included the WHERE clause in the proper position. Thanks for your help too!